# Как распаковать вот такое вот значение в python

Tags: python, list

Подскажите как распаковать вот это

```
['Диаметр возвратного провода [мм]', '10']['Наружный диаметр [мм]', '75']['Выпускн.-? [мм]', '8']['Впускн. ? [мм]', '8']['Высота [мм]', '131']
```

Чтоб получилось

```
Диаметр возвратного провода мм 10
```

и т.д в цикле

Comment: как вы пробовали? какие проблемы? давайте ваш код осудим

Comment: А где запятые между списками? Что это вообще?

Comment: **bold** `
parametrs =  response['result']['parameters']
param = []
    for i in parametrs:
        parametr_name = i['name']
        parametr_value = i['value']
        param.append([parametr_name, parametr_value])
    final_res = (''.join(str(x) for x in param))

`
после этого я получаю то что показал выше, мне бы понять как извлечь те данные ключ значение и записать их в csv

Comment: `[{'name': 'Диаметр возвратного провода [мм]', 'value': '10'}, {'name': 'Наружный диаметр [мм]', 'value': '75'}, {'name': 'Выпускн.-? [мм]', 'value': '8'}, {'name': 'Впускн. ? [мм]', 'value': '8'}, {'name': 'Высота [мм]', 'value': '131'}]` 
Это если просто выводить `parametrs`

Comment: Вот это вот все и надо писать в вопросе,  а не коментах  есть кнопочка править

Comment: @splash58, а мне понравилась ваша опечатка или это не опечатка?(осудим или обсудим)

Comment: @СергейШ будет зависеть от кода :)

Comment: Нашел выход
`parametrs =  response['result']['parameters']
    for i in range(len(parametrs)):
        names = parametrs[i]['name']
        values = parametrs[i]['value']
        print(names,values)`
но как это правильно записать в файл?
Да код может быть не красив но я ток начинаю
Прошу прощения перед гикамия)
вывод таков 
*Диаметр возвратного провода [мм] 10
Наружный диаметр [мм] 75
Выпускн.-? [мм] 8
Впускн. ? [мм] 8
Высота [мм] 131*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python позволяет распаковывать массивы и кортежи на несколько переменных, например:

```py
data = ["яблоко", "апельсин"]
value1, value2 = data
print(value1)
# яблоко
print(value2)
# апельсин
```

В вашем случае получается список, состоящий из списков, соответственно, если вам нужно получить это в виде переменных нужно использовать ту же конструкцию, но в цикле. Например:

```
data = [["яблоко", "апельсин"], ["груша", "мандарин"]]
for value1, value2 in data:
    print(value1)  # 1-я итерация: яблоко, 2-я итерация: груша
    print(value2)  # 1-я итерация: апельсин, 2-я итерация: мандарин
```

Соответственно, дальше вы можете комбинировать эти переменные как вам угодно